# When to use React combined with Django?

Tags: django, reactjs, redux

I've been working with the django framework and mostly have been using html templates for its front end but im wondering whether i should switch to React if it's a big project? Alternativelyl, can i create a user interface application without using React as front end or is React / ReactRedux advisable when using Django?

Can you achieve greater functionality with React when manipulating the front-end as opposed to using views in Django?

Answer (score 1):

Advice for when to use React does not have to do something with Django. It mainly depends on the complexity of the application that is to be developed. If you have, or will have a Web application with a complex frontend, containing many functionalities and quirks, which can grow to a large codebase, it is a good idea to use one of today's popular frameworks such as React, Vue or Angular. They allow you to divide the large codebase into components and manage them more easily.

So, the short answer is - if it is going to become a large and complex application, it is a good idea to use React. Otherwise, Django templates will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your application's frontend getting larger and larger and you feel that your are repeating too much html page for example , you might want to use a SPA and component based framework to reuse the components across the application.
2. If you want to separate backend and frontend code to acquire more maintainability and separation of concerns that might be the reason
3. If There will be more than one clients(Web, IOS, Android etc.) it is a good idea to separate backend code from frontend(client)
4. Frontend framework will bring more structure to your application therefore it will be more easier to maintain the project

Otherwise Django templates are good to build a fast project like a few form entries and an introduction page etc.